I can't install argon2 python
I'm trying to install argon2 via pip install argon2 but it keeps giving an error, I've already installed openssl, builds tools, argon2-cffi
C:\Users\jefer>pip install argon2
Collecting argon2
  Using cached argon2-0.1.10.tar.gz (28 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: argon2
  Building wheel for argon2 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [42 lines of output]
      C:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u6pndo1w\argon2_a9eb90795db04f9a949f69c3032d17d9\setup.py:27: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\O'
        library_dirs = ['c:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib']
      C:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u6pndo1w\argon2_a9eb90795db04f9a949f69c3032d17d9\setup.py:29: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\O'
        includes = ['c:\OpenSSL-Win32\include', 'argon2-windows-stubs/include']
      Warning: 'classifiers' should be a list, got type 'tuple'
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      copying argon2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      running build_ext
      building '_argon2' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\phc-winner-argon2
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\phc-winner-argon2\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\phc-winner-argon2\src\blake2
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/argon2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/argon2.obj
      argon2.c
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2/blake2b.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2/blake2b.obj
      blake2b.c
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/core.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/core.obj
      core.c
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.obj
      encoding.c
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(334): warning C4267: '=': conversÆo de 'size_t' para 'uint32_t', poss¡vel perda de dados
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(339): warning C4267: '=': conversÆo de 'size_t' para 'uint32_t', poss¡vel perda de dados
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(347): warning C4267: '=': conversÆo de 'size_t' para 'uint32_t', poss¡vel perda de dados
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(407): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(409): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
      ./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c(411): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/ref.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/ref.obj
      ref.c
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tc./phc-winner-argon2/src/thread.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/thread.obj
      thread.c
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dinline=__inline -I./phc-winner-argon2 -I./phc-winner-argon2/src -I./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2 -Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Iargon2-windows-stubs/include -IC:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tc./src/argon2_py.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\./src/argon2_py.obj
      argon2_py.c
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib /LIBPATH:C:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\jefer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22621.0\\um\x64" libeay32.lib advapi32.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__argon2 build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/argon2.obj build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2/blake2b.obj build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/core.obj build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.obj build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/ref.obj build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src/thread.obj build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\./src/argon2_py.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\_argon2.cp312-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\./phc-winner-argon2/src\_argon2.cp312-win_amd64.lib
      LINK : fatal error LNK1181: nÆo foi poss¡vel abrir o arquivo de entrada 'libeay32.lib'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1181
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for argon2
  Running setup.py clean for argon2
Failed to build argon2
ERROR: Could not build wheels for argon2, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Can anyone help me please, I've tried everything I'm using Windows 11, Visual Studio Code, I've already added the openssl PATH

The package argon2 is from December 2015; are you sure you want to install it?

Yes, any specific reason not to install?

Not directly, but the package or some of its dependencies might not work properly anymore with argon2.

Have you tried searching for libeay32, since that library appears to be missing?

Combining my above two comments: did libeay32 come with the OpenSSL installation?

Also: you've added OpenSSL to PATH, but going by other OSes (I'm not familiar with Windows, but that's something that you can look up), you'll may have to set something like a library path instead, so the library is picked up; PATH is usually for executables.
